# Jruby - Create jar, no such file to load

Tags: ruby, jar, jruby

i am trying create a jar of my jruby project(actually there is  only ruby code at the time), but, usgin [rawr](http://rawr.rubyforge.org/) i create a jar with success, but when i run it:

Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- ../lib/person
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033)
    at Kernel.require(file:/Users/edipofederle/Projeto/socialAPI/package/jar/lib/java/jruby-complete.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
    at (Anonymous).(root)(./bin/main.rb:2)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1033)
    at (Anonymous).(root)(./bin/main.rb:1)

My folder structure is basically a bin folder with main.rb  file and a lib folder with person.rb file.

I am available for further clarification.

Someone can me help. thanks

Comment: What are the contents of both of your files?

Answer (score 1):

my mistake, i was puting ruby src file into wrong folder. works now.

Thanks

Comment: The folder structure now is: /Project/-> bin, lib, src, package